# PHP regex string and substract part

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and i need the number 3 to do an action

```
$string  =  '<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:block {"ref":3} /--></div>';
```

I have this preg_match which works to detect.

```
preg_match('/<!-- wp:block {"ref":[0-9]*} \/-->/',$string)
```

How can i output just number 3 from the `$string` not knowing what's before `<!-- wp:block {"ref":` ?

Comment: `if (preg_match('/<!-- wp:block {"ref":([0-9]*)} \/-->/',$string, $matches)) { echo $matches[1]; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this- `preg_match('/<!-- wp:block {"ref":([0-9]*)} \/-->/',$string, $matches);`

Then use `$matches[1]` to get the number.